# UINavigationController & UITableviewController with different number of sublevels

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm working in an app with 1 master table view.

There are cells leading to a `detailview` after going through 1, 2 or 3 `tableview` levels based on certain parameters (for example `BOOL` sub).

The app behaviour is as follows:

`UINavigationController` -> `UITableViewController` (sub == YES) -> `UITableViewController` (sub == NO)-> `DetailViewController`

`UINavigationController` -> `UITableViewController` (sub == YES) -> `UITableViewController` (sub == YES) -> `UITableViewController` (sub == NO) -> `DetailViewController`

And so on (max 3 levels).

Someone knows how to do that (using `storyboard`) with just 1 `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define two "generic" segues called `"toDetail"` and `"toNextLevel"` in the story board from your table view controller. One segue should lead to the detail controller; the other one should lead back to the table view controller. Then, implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method with a condition that moves you to the next level when there is one, or to the detail screen when there is no next level:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([myModel rowHasNextLevel:indexPath.row]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNextLevel" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
    }
}
```